# jQuery Mobile: how to make buttons that don't reload the page (href)?

Tags: jquery-mobile

According to the [jQuery 1.1.0 Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0) a button should be defined as a link.

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>
```

This loads the referenced page.

When using the # it reloads the current page.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button">Action</a>
```

How could we define a button that is not a link and simply triggers an event handler when an event on it occurs ?

**Edit:** my interpretation of what I saw was wrong. Clicking on a button with href="#" doesn't reload the page. I should delete the question because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: so you want to prevent the default behavior of the hyperlink when user clicks it?

Comment: Yes. When used on my Android phone I see the header beeing redrawn. I suspect I'm doing something inefficient. On iPad the header is not redrawn.

Comment: Well, you could just do this in jquery
$('a').click(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: or just <a href="#" OnClick="return false;" data-role="button">Action</a>
which is simpler

Comment: Could you point out where in the docs it has a # refreshed the page?

Comment: @Efthimis I just notice I misinterpreted what I saw. Using href="#" doesn't refresh the page. I was wrong. I made a confusion with another operation where I change the content of a list item and then call .listview('refresh'). It is the header text that is then redrawn. So my question is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding the `href="#"` does not refresh the page, Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/XNLWS/

Here are the jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

If you're looking for a custom event, here is an example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/XNLWS/1/

JS:

```
$( "#myButton" ).bind( "click", function(event, ui) {
    alert('Custom action here');
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="myButton">Link button</a>
    </div>
</div>​
```